# How to install g++ 4.4 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, g++

There is a Debian [g++-4.4](http://packages.debian.org/experimental/g++-4.4) package,
but it's not Ubuntu.  There are too many system-destroyed scary stories on the web.

How can I install g++ 4.4 on Ubuntu?

Comment: I can't imagine that you would destroy your system compiling it yourself. At worst you would just not be able to compile it.

Comment: Compiling is not a problem. installing without dpkg is.

Comment: Just don't install it to /usr. Put it in your home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this URL. I installed gcc-4.4 (and g++-4.4) from there, which seem to be the most official group of hackers that actually put gcc-4.4 into an ubuntu .deb. Till now running without problems :

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain/+archive/ppa

Regards.

Comment: I added repository gcc-4.4 installs fine, but g++-4.4 gives error that libc6 >=2.8 is not available. While I have it installed. Any ideas?

Comment: These repositories are for jaunty. What ubuntu distribution do you have?

Answer (score 17):

I recomend you install build-essential package that contains g++.

Type it in your terminal:

> $ sudo apt-get install build-essential

Then confirm installation.

Answer (score 2):

Debian packages should work on Ubuntu. It is based on Debian.

Edit: Try this :

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-snapshot
```

Comment: Or wait until ubuntu provides it. GCC 4.4 was just released and it may take a while for distributions to provide packages for it.

Comment: I don't think he wants to wait 6 months for the next Ubuntu release.

Comment: Isn't it that debian and ubuntu packages are binary-incompatible?

Comment: Ubuntu and Debian are binary compatible, AFAIK. If you are worried about binary compatibility, use gcc-snapshot (a Ubuntu package).

Comment: "debian experimental packages won't work with ubuntu- mostly because ubuntu is built differently, despite being debian-based." from https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/16018

Is it not true any more?

Comment: gcc-snapshot (20081024-0ubuntu1)
http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/gcc-snapshot
If the date is right, there can't be gcc-4.4
And is there g++ at all?

Comment: Thanks Zifire 

$ /usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/bin/g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 20081024-0ubuntu1) 4.4.0 20081024 (experimental) [trunk revision 141342]

It's quite old.

Answer (score 1):

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain/%2Barchive/ppa

Answer (score 1):

From your terminal type `sudo apt-get install g++`. It's been working great for me!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against it. Requiring a newer version of g++ will require that if you use any new features of 4.4 then your users will also require a 4.4 runtime library. That being said, I would just download the source, `./configure --ALLMYOPTS&&make && sudo make install`. If you want to make a gcc similar to the one shipped with Ubuntu, `apt-get source gcc` and look in debian/rules for their configure flags (they may be applied on multiple lines).

Comment: Compiling GCC is much harder than it sounds.

Comment: sudo make install is a bad, bad, *bad* idea. Why not simply configure --prefix=/home/whatever/some/path/here and make install as that user?

Comment: Running "sudo make install" is the way to install this for all users of your system, right? Or would you plan on installing this to your home directory and then moving it to prevent the install script from doing anything untoward? Not trying to be critical, just curious why you think this is so terrible.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in a debian repository, it should would under Ubuntu no problem. If you would like to add a repository, simply follow the directions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/add-applications/C/extra-repositories-adding.html).