# Cannot install g++ in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, g++, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

I have just installed ubuntu 12.04. Now, I want to install g++. So, I run the command:

**sudo apt-get install g++**

But I receive the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  g++-4.6 libstdc++6-4.6-dev
Suggested packages:
  g++-multilib g++-4.6-multilib gcc-4.6-doc libstdc++6-4.6-dbg libstdc++6-4.6-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  g++ g++-4.6 libstdc++6-4.6-dev
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,745 kB/8,389 kB of archives.
After this operation, 24.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main g++-4.6 i386 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  Could not connect to 113.171.224.178:80 (113.171.224.178). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.6/g++-4.6_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb  Could not connect to 113.171.224.178:80 (113.171.224.178). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Next, I run the command:

**sudo apt-get update**

And I also receive others

```
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                               
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]                     
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                     
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                       
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [65.1 kB]       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                            
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB]                             
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                         
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [1,950 B]                     
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [24.0 kB]                       
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [1,380 B]                    
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [245 kB]                     
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources [5,470 B]                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                     
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB]                            
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources [934 kB]                                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                                         
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [3,968 B]              
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [73.0 kB]                
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2,369 B]              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en                            
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US                                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex                               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                                 
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [374 kB]                          
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [5,494 B]                   
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [83.4 kB]                     
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [4,746 B]                   
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [603 kB]                    
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [10.1 kB]             
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [194 kB]                
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [10.4 kB]             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex                          
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources/DiffIndex                    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources/DiffIndex                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex                    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex              
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en                               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources                                    
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex [3,341 kB]       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en                         
Fetched 7,012 kB in 19s (352 kB/s)                                                                 
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_restricted_i18n_Index

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

To check the repository, I run the command: **cat /etc/apt/sources.list**. Below is the output

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20130213)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Please help me to install g++ on Ubuntu. The version of gcc is 4.6.3

Thank you so much

Comment: may this link useful for u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784063/how-to-install-g-4-4-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd faced a similar issue few months back. I changed the repository server from lk.archive.ubuntu.com (which ubuntu had installed by default) to ubuntu main server which is archive.ubuntu.com. Did an "apt-get update" after that and all went smooth.

The regional servers are down sometimes. You may also try changing from the US to the main server. You can do this either by hand editing the /etc/apt/sources.list file or from the ubuntu software centre in a click of a button.