# MATLAB MEX C++ file Compiling error g++ command not found

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, g++, mex

I'm trying to compile a C++ file (`mysql.cpp`) in MATLAB with MEX Function on Linux server.
I'm getting this error which I'm not able to figure out why?

```
/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/mex: line 1343: g++: command not found
mex: compile of ' "mysql.cpp"' failed.
```

I use this command:

```
mex -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient mysql.cpp
```

and here are the MEX Compiler Configuration Details: -

```
-> mexopts.sh sourced from directory (DIR = $PREF_DIR)

   FILE = /root/.matlab/R2013a/mexopts.sh

----------------------------------------------------------------
-> MATLAB             = /opt/MATLAB/R2013a

-> CC                 = gcc

-> CC flags:

  CFLAGS             = -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread

   CDEBUGFLAGS        = -g

   COPTIMFLAGS        = -O -DNDEBUG

   CLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++

   arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32

-> CXX                = g++

-> CXX flags:

   CXXFLAGS           = -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread

   CXXDEBUGFLAGS      = -g

   CXXOPTIMFLAGS      = -O -DNDEBUG

   CXXLIBS            = -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/opt/MATLAB/R2013a
/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm

   arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32

-> FC                 = gfortran

-> FC flags:

   FFLAGS             = -fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer

   FDEBUGFLAGS        = -g

   FOPTIMFLAGS        = -O

   FLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/opt/MATLAB/R2013a
/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm

   arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32

-> LD                 = g++

-> Link flags:

   LDFLAGS            = -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/opt/MATLAB/R2013a/extern
/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined

   LDDEBUGFLAGS       = -g

   LDOPTIMFLAGS       = -O

   LDEXTENSION        = .mexa64

   arguments          =  -Lusr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient

-> LDCXX                 =


-> Link flags:

   LDCXXFLAGS         =

   LDCXXDEBUGFLAGS    =

   LDCXXOPTIMFLAGS    =

   LDCXXEXTENSION     =

   arguments          =  -Lusr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient
```

Please help me to find out what is wrong.

Comment: it seems you have no the compiler installed. How to install it, it depends on the distro you are using. In Ubuntu `apt-get install build-essential`, see also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784063/how-to-install-g-4-4-on-ubuntu

Comment: so i need to install g++ compiler separately?

Comment: you need it of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you should install a compiler before compiling. Mex is just a tool which calls one underneath and since g++ is the C++ compiler of gcc you should install this one.

As far as I know it will still not work, because matlab supports only gcc 4.3 (not sure about that). So install a gcc and run
    mex -setup

Afterwards you should be able to compile.

Comment: the first time i tried to compile, i got a message like GCC Version 4.4.X required for the MATLAB Version "".. I'm using MATLAB R2013a.. then i installed GCC 4.4.7 but still I'm getting this error..

Comment: i infact installed gcc c++ 4.5.0-2.el6 from epel repository. but the same issue

Comment: is there a way to know where the executable is actually searched? if you run `g++ --version` from a shell, what version do you obtain?

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: i was finally able to compile the c++ file. Actually the version of GCC was the problem with some missing library files and dependency issues for difference of version between MySQL Client and gcc. i downloaded new version of MySQL Connector and i used this command:   'mex -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lpthread -ldl mysql.cpp'.   thank you very much for the help people.